# ES6 class - accessing instance variables

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, instance

I am working on a webapp where I have pages with multiple horizontally scrolling panels.  I want to handle the horiziontal scroll via my own vanilla JS code.  Given that I need to do this many times over I thought I would wrap that functionality in an ES6 class.  My effort are along the following lines

```
class HoriScroll 
{
 constructor(id)
 {
  this.target = document.getElementById(id);
  this.target.addEventListener('touchstart',this.slideStart,{passive:true});
  this.target.addEventListener('touchmove',this.slideMove,{passive:true});
  this.target.dataset.startX = null;
  this.target.dataset.startTime = null;
  this.target.dataset.movePending = false;
 }

 slideStart(e)
 {
  if (1 === e.changedTouches.length) 
  {
   this.dataset.startX = e.changedTouches[0].screenX;
   this.dataset.startTime = Date.now();
  } 
 }
}
```

While I will be able to get things working this way what bothers me is the rather clumsy way I am recording `startX`, `startTime` etc - as attributes of the `dataset` of the horizontal scroll target HTML element.  I ended up doing this since I cannot work out a way to access instance variable values in the class.  For instance in `slideStart` `this` refers to the HTML element instance, not the `HoriScroll` class instance.

How, if at all, can this be done.

Comment: `this.slideStart` -> `() => this.slideStart()`

Comment: It will work as you said `this` inside the `slideStart` refers to the Html element, not the class itself. You can use an arrow function as @VLAZ suggests or you can bind `slideStart.bind(this)` to the class instance

Comment: Correction to @VLAZ comment. Here is what you can do from my constructor 

`this.target.addEventListener('touchstart',(e)=>this.slideStart(e),{passive:true}`

Without having access to the event parameter, `e` the actual touch event cannot be accessed although the class instance variables are now accessible!